# brew installation of elasticsearch failing

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, macos, elasticsearch, homebrew

Been trying to install ElasticSearch using brew, however, all my attempts fail and error

```
    Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  NoMethodError: undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  paths
```

is fired back at me. anyone ever crossed this?
brew install --debug output is:

```
➜  ~ brew install --debug elasticsearch
Updating Homebrew...
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/elasticsearch.rb
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromPathLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/elasticsearch.rb
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  NoMethodError: undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  paths
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/os/mac/extend/ENV/super.rb:112:in `setup_build_environment'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:88:in `install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:196:in `<main>'
```

thanks!

Comment: This error is not specific to elasticsearch.  I see the same problem when trying to install sbt or scala on a Mac.  The problem is that `sdk` is undefined in `super.rb`.  Traces back to `MacOS.sdk_for_formula(formula)` returning nil on line 110.

Answer (score 6):

Eventually it was due to the fact xcode was outdated. Updating xcode fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip David.  My Xcode upgrade failed because a couple of packages were so old that their signatures expired.  To make brew happy, I renamed these packages so that Xcode ignores them: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/MobileDeviceDevelopment.pkg
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/MobileDevice.pkg

Answer (score 1):

The instructions for [Installing Elasticsearch on macOS with Homebrew](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/brew.html#brew) on the elastic website suggest using a different formula, namely:

```
brew tap elastic/tap
```

then

```
brew install elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full
```

or

```
brew install elastic/tap/elasticsearch-oss
```

depending on whether you want the non-Free (but still $0.00) or OSS version.

I haven't actually tried that formula myself, but I have just had success on macOS Catalina with `brew install openjdk@11` to get the required Java version, then I installed the tarfile of logstash-7.6.2 by hand, making sure to do `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11` before running the logstash program; I assume the same approach will work with elasticsearch, although the official formula above is probably simpler.

Comment: that was actually how I installed. but it was still the same outcome :(

Answer (score 0):

The following is a temporary work-around until Homebrew is fixed.

1. [Disable the Homebrew auto-update](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/1670) by either prefixing your brew commands like this: `HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install elasticsearch` or setting an environment variable in your Bash .profile as `export HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1`.  (I am using the latter.)
2. If you have Homebrew installed as a GIT repository under /usr/local/Homebrew, go to that directory to review the GIT log.  You should see a recent merge to the `stable` branch introduced new code to super.rb:

   > `2ae2680 (tag: 2.2.12, stable) Merge pull request #7301 from Bo98/cmake-sdkroot`
3. You want to checkout a previous commit in your /usr/local/Homebrew git repo.  This did the trick for me:

   <strike>/usr/local/Homebrew> git checkout stable^</strike>
   <strike>HEAD is now at 6e3a293... Merge pull request #7300 from bayandin/patch-1</strike>

> CORRECTION!  The "stable" branch moved recently to `2.2.13`.  The commit history still contains the problem commit: `2ae2680 (tag: 2.2.12) Merge pull request #7301 from Bo98/cmake-sdkroot`.

Checkout the commit-before-the-tag instead.

```
/usr/local/Homebrew> git checkout -q 2.2.12^
/usr/local/Homebrew> git branch -vv --no-color
* (HEAD detached at 6e3a293) 6e3a293 Merge pull request #7300 from bayandin/patch-1
   master c9ffde6 [origin/master] Merge pull request #7351 from Bo98/branch-encode
   stable 3d9cf83 Merge pull request #7346 from Bo98/pr-pull
```

4. When you are ready to undo the changes in step #3, running `brew update` will checkout the `stable` branch (at whatever state that will be).

Comment: followed the solution however still encountering: Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  NoMethodError: undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  paths

Comment: Thanks, David.  I corrected my answer that should checkout before the tag, rather than relative to a moving branch.

Comment: hey guys, I tried updating my xcode and that fixed it, oddly enough. did you guys make sure your xcode is updated?